# Zip and unzip suggestions?

Tags: wix, zip, unzip

Is there any possible ways to unzip a folder using XML Source.

Comment: Your question is unclear.. are you sure this has to do with Wix (http://wixtoolset.org/) ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a best practice to shove a .ZIP into an .MSI install and then merely extract it at install time.  It defeats many features of Windows Installer such as rollback, upgrade, uninstall, version conflict management, transformation, resiliency and so on.